# Spring MVC exception when i try to read object

Tags: spring-mvc

i'm new with spring MVC and i'm trying to perform my first application. my objective is to have one web form used to take a string as input and another web form where i write the string on a web page.

i created the following files:

the controller:

```
package com.gipeto.app;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.prova.form.Prova;
import com.prova.form.User;

@Controller
public class NewController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/secondaPagina", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView goToPage(ModelMap model) {
    Prova funziona = new Prova();
    funziona.setTest("pippo");
    model.addAttribute("prova", funziona);

    return new ModelAndView("secondPage","model",model);    
    }
}
```

my homepage:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<button onclick="window.location.href='secondaPagina'"> entra </button>
</body>
</html>
```

The second page.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@  taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test2</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>nome</td>
        <td>sesso</td>
        <td>età</td>                
    </tr>
    <tr> 

    <form:input path="test"/>

    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type=submit value="salva">
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to run this code i obtain the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/secondPage.jsp] at line [17]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/secondPage.jsp] at line [17]

14:     </tr>
15:     <tr> 
16:     
17:     <form:input path="test"/>
18:                     
19:     </tr>
20:   </table>
```

Can you help me to understand where is the issue?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because you don't actually have the form:form tag. Try it like this.

```
<form:form method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>nome</td>
            <td>sesso</td>
            <td>età</td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form:input path="test"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type=submit value="salva">
</form:form>
```